# Activating and using Unity 2019.x for Windows without the Unity Hub

Tags: windows, unity3d

Is it possible to activate and actually use the personal edition of Unity without using the Unity hub?

My reasons for this - my students (about 50 of them, aged 10-13) want to experiment in Unity. I want to make a simple, easy to follow tutorial for their parents, regarding the downloading and installation of Unity and Visual Studio.

Vast majority of the parents aren't tech persons, and the whole installation process is fine, until the activation and the Hub business is reached.

If it's not possible, what's the last version which would work without the Hub?

**EDIT**

The [officially recommended way of doing it](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/Manual/InstallingUnity.html) is not working the way I'd like it to work (without the Hub). I am able to download and install Unity, but when I want to start it, a message shows, informing me that:

> To use Unity, you must have an active license. Please download the Unity Hub and activate your license.

Again, I just want to be able to activate and use Unity without the Hub, if it's possible.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/Manual/InstallingUnity.html

Comment: @Moab Nope, not working. Will add this to the question, thanks.